# Register Simple Form Type Service since Symfony 3.0

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

> [Since 2.8 version](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md), Symfony has introduced alternatively support to fully-qualified class names to build forms, since 3.0 it's mandatory.

Long before, there is a habit around that to register form types even if they have no dependencies. Suppose you a simple form type **without dependencies**:

```
class FoobarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo', NumberType::class)
            ->add('bar', TextType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

we try to use it somewhere:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('foobar1', FoobarType::class)
    ->add('foobar2', FoobarType::class)
    ->add('foobar3', FoobarType::class)
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

and all works fine! then if we had the service:

```
services:
    app.form.type.foobar:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\FoobarType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

because we used the `form.type` tag, our service will be used instead of creating a new `FoobarType` ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)). I've tried to make the difference, but the form type was resolved/instanced just one time as well as the service works.

so, my questions are:

- **There is some well-known issue for unregistered form types usage?**
- **Then, we can to say that form types can be used without register it as `form.type` service?**

*Note that I'm talking about simple form type (no dependencies)*

Comment: Having trouble understanding your question.  There is no need to register form types as services unless you want to inject dependencies.  The bad thing about the S3 approach is that you can no longer create several services using the same form type class nor can you use a service to "override" the form type at runtime.  It is all class name dependent.

Comment: @Cerad I've seen some comments (from Symfony Core) expressing that is necessary to register the form type always, unfortunately I could not find the comment, but this has occasioned doubt.

Comment: The manual is often a good place to look for these sorts of things.

Comment: It is not mandatory to register form type. As @Cerad pointed out, it's necessary only when you have dependencies